# overwrite pdf file not showing new data

Tags: python, pdf

I have problem with overwrite pdf file, its working perfectly, until i add new date, and press generate pdf file, showing only old file. I need use `ctrl + F5` to see new file. So i think cache keeping info about old pdf file.
Im using python and FPDF for generate pdf file. Then pdf file generated, im overwrite old pdf file.

```
_f = '/files/test'
if os.path.exists(_f): os.remove(_f)
pdf.output(_f, 'F')
```

Possible add some code, for clear cache in browser to see not old, but new pdf file? Or maybe you know  some another way to solve my problem? Thank you.